# couldn't find file 'angularjs/rails/resource' with type 'application/javascript'):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, asset-pipeline

Error come on this line

```
//= require angularjs/rails/resource
```

It gives an error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'angularjs/rails/resource' with type 'application/javascript'):
```

Gemfile

```
# angularjs
gem 'angularjs-rails-resource'
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'angular_rails_csrf'
```

Comment: Did you restart your server after installing the new gems? For passenger, `touch tmp/restart.txt`, and for `rails s`, just kill the process and start again.

Comment: Yes I restart.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `angularjs-rails` gem.
This works fine for me

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
```

Then in your `.js` file you can require like

```
//= require angular
//= require angular-resource
```